# How to link my own .so file instead of OS bundle .so file?

Tags: c++, c, hyperlink, compilation, libcurl

1. My build command

   g++ -g -m64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -I./curl-7.60.0/include -I./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/ ./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.4.7/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.7_libmt.so **./curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4.5.0** tests.cpp -otests
2. The .so file exsists

   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 pswluna developer 529763 2018-05-30 18:48 ./curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4.5.0
3. But ldd result is... (please see the 3rd line.)

   ```
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd4f5f1000)
   ./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.4.7/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.7_libmt.so (0x00007f833daec000)
   libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000003b0e600000)
   libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003eb5c00000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003eab000000)
   libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003eb4c00000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003eaac00000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003eab400000)
   libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x0000003ec0c00000)
   libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x0000003461200000)
   librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003eac000000)
   libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003088600000)
   libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003087a00000)
   libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003088a00000)
   libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003eb7000000)
   libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003eabc00000)
   libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x0000003ebb800000)
   libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x0000003ebbc00000)
   libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x0000003eba800000)
   libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x0000003eb9800000)
   libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x0000003eb9400000)
   libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x0000003eb9c00000)
   libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x0000003eba000000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003eab800000)
   libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x0000003089a00000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003eaa800000)
   liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x0000003ebe800000)
   libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003ead000000)
   libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x0000003466800000)
   libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003088200000)
   libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003eb7400000)
   libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003088e00000)
   libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003087e00000)
   libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x0000003460600000)
   libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003086200000)
   libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x000000345f600000)
   ```

Please help me...................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g++ -g -m64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -I./curl-7.60.0/include -I./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/ ./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.4.7/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.7_libmt.so ./curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4.5.0 tests.cpp -otests

This command *does* link the library you want: `./curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4.5.0`, but it *doesn't* arrange for that library to be used at runtime.

Here is the command you want:

```
g++ -g -m64 -I./curl-7.60.0/include -I./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/ \
  tests.cpp \
 -L./jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.4.7 -ljson_linux-gcc-4.4.7_libmt \
 -L./curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs -l:libcurl.so.4.5.0 \
 -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/libs/linux-gcc-4.4.7 \
 -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)/curl-7.60.0/lib/.libs \
 -otests
```

Explanation:

1. You want to use `-rpath` to tell the dynamic loader *where* it should search for libraries at runtime
2. `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` *only* makes sense when you build a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit OS, but you aren't doing that
3. `-fPIC` is completely unnecessary when you are building main executable.
4. The order of sources and libraries on command line *matters*, your order is *wrong*.